# Sharepoint 2013 - Is it possible to copy an HTML Master Page without breaking it?

Tags: 2013, master-page, sharepoint-server

This might seem like a newb question.. but since Master Pages have all those custom ASP.NET Server Control IDs which will give errors if they are not associated with the original master page. Can anyone give an educated answer on this?

I'm also asking because, I copied a master page and now every time I make changes to the master page. It completely breaks and looks as though all of the SharePoint Web Controls (Navigation etc) have broken away from the page. This happens even when I only put a single *space* and save the master page.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you change? And are you editing the .html files, or the .master files?

Comment: Are you changing the .master file itself? SharePoint 2013 actually introduces the .html file for the masterpage which is dynamically converted to .master file (so you don't touch .master file directly).. Go to Settings -> Design Manager and take it from there..

Comment: Checkout [A guide to quick SharePoint 2013 branding](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/26/a-guide-to-quick-sharepoint-2013-branding/) & [SharePoint 2013 – Design Manager – Convert HTML to Master Page](http://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/sharepoint-2013-design-manager-convert-html-to-master-page/)

Comment: Hello  - Yes I am changing only the html page. This is where the problem is happening